# Change default background color while deleting a row from tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my app, I changed the background color of every view to dark. But when I delete a row from tableView, row background changed to white. Why and how can I fix it?

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Reveal]

```
tableView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.1922, green:0.1922, blue:0.1922, alpha:1.0)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.1922, green:0.1922, blue:0.1922, alpha:1.0)
        if dataManagement.taskData.count != 0{
            for rowIndex in 0...tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - 1 {
                let cellPath = IndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: 0)
                if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: cellPath) as? TaskListTableViewCell {
                    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.1922, green:0.1922, blue:0.1922, alpha:1.0)
                    cell.taskLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
                }
            }
        }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { //可删除
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskListTableViewCell
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        if dataManagement.taskData[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].id == dataManagement.currentTask {
            dataManagement.currentTask = nil
            dataManagement.historyIsSelected = true
            pomodoroTimer.stop()
        }
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: Show relevant code please.

Comment: show the code that you used to create the table and delete the row

Comment: Table is in UITableViewController. I just added my code. @LinusGeffarth

Comment: Same problem here. Any workaround yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround from Realm Swift document.

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realm-notifications

They're using async to trigger the updates.
So I think we just need to avoid calling `delete`, `insert` or `update` methods in the scope of `UITableViewDelegate`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        boards.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        // use async to avoid showing white background.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the background of the cell programmatically using:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor <yourcolor>];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have already changed cell background color.

Answer (score 0):

You have add below single line code in **commit editingStyle** method may be it's help you!!

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.1922, green:0.1922, blue:0.1922, alpha:1.0)
```

Or simple use following code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { //可删除
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskListTableViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.1922, green:0.1922, blue:0.1922, alpha:1.0) // set cell background color here!!

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        if dataManagement.taskData[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].id == dataManagement.currentTask {
            dataManagement.currentTask = nil
            dataManagement.historyIsSelected = true
            pomodoroTimer.stop()
        }
     tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
   }
}
```