# Swift 4, Background color goes white when deleting cell

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have found similar questions. None of which solve the same problem I am having.
This one here: [Table view cell background goes white when deleting a cell - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182311/table-view-cell-background-goes-white-when-deleting-a-cell-ios)
is in objective c. I need a swift answer.

I found this [Change default background color while deleting a row from tableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47102469/change-default-background-color-while-deleting-a-row-from-tableview) 
Answer in swift however when I add this to my code it still does not work.

Here is the code I am using to delete the cell.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "delete") { (action, indexPath) in

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "Are you sure you want to delete this?", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) in
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            })
            alertController.addAction(deleteAction)

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)


            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        return [delete]
    }
```

I need to maintain the color of the cell as the delete option comes from swiping.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reload the table after deleting cell and also remove cell data from the array as well or use this line in view did load

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

this will remove the empty cell form table